# How to Add Snippet to SnippetPlus in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Having SinppetPlus v 1.4.0.0 and Notepad++ v 6.0 installed on Windows 7 64 bit, I am not able to add new Snippets or modify  and rename the existing snippet. Can you please let me know if this plugin still is working with Notepad++ v6.0? Or I am doing some thing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You may ask http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of SnippetPlus.
Actually you can still add or modify snippets but they appear after restarting Notepad++.

This is not by design. Actually I recreated SnippetPlus version 1.4 from scratch and simply forget to add the refresh funcionality.
Write me directly on my email and I will send you the fixed version or you can wait till I find time to update it on the site.

Raj

Comment: Did you add the refresh functionality or still? @Rajesh